# Pry not loading local app environment in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry

I recently installed pry to replace my irb.  It was working fine at first, but now every time I run pry it doesn't recognize the local app environment at all.  I get something like the following:

```
[3] pry(main)> show-models
NameError: undefined local variable or method `show' for main:Object
from (pry):2:in `__pry__'
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the pry-rails gem and I've added the following code to an initializer file:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Use Pry instead of IRB
  silence_warnings do
    begin
      require 'pry'
      IRB = Pry
    rescue LoadError
    end
  end
end
```

Any thoughts on what this could be?  I can't seem to find any info on this.

My gem file looks like this:

```
group :development, :test do

  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-byebug'

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what it was, but a system restart did the trick.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You probably run Pry using `pry` command, when you should be using `rails console` command (be sure that you run it from your Rails app directory). If that doesn't work for you, then try `bin/rails console` and `bundle exec rails console` commands.

Comment: When I run rails console I get an error: 
lorenzsell$ rails console
Running via Spring preloader in process 39543
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/completion.rb:11:in `<top (required)>': IRB is not a module (TypeError)

Comment: Delete that initializer you've added. pry-rails doesn't require any initializers to work [[source](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails#installation)].

Answer (score 0):

**I also Use pry**

I'm also using pry and not seen command like `show-models` yet. It doesn't work for me too. And I never use such command. Using `Model.all` working fine.I don't if commands you are using is feature of pry. If so visit its documentation. I think its problem due to you gave wrong command.

Comment: no, Models.all doesn't work for me either.  I get a similar error: [1] pry(main)> Models.all
NameError: uninitialized constant Models
from (pry):1:in `__pry__'

Comment: Sorlry no models only Model.all

Answer (score 0):

I had some different problems using `pry` and `byebug` together.

i deleted `byebug` and all is well.

Hope it will also solve ur problem.

I use `gem 'pry'` in my gemfile instead of `gem 'pry-rails'` though

Comment: I run pry and byebug together with no issues.